# State if this sequence is monotonic

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have this sequence $a_n$
$$\frac{1}{n\ln(n)}$$
And I want (by definition) prove that it is decreasing ($a(n)>a(n+1)$). I don't know what to do with this inequality.

$(n+1)\ln(n+1)>n\ln(n)$

thx a lot

Answer (score 3):

$x \ln x$ is an increasing function on $[1,\infty)$ because it is a product of two nonnegative increasing functions. Hence $n\ln n$ is increasing.

Answer (score 0):

For $n>1$:

$\color{blue}{n+1>n}>0,$

and then $\color{blue}{\ln(n+1)>\ln(n)}>0$

so $(n+1)\ln(n+1)>n\ln (n).$

Comment: One should add that all terms in the inequalities are positive before multiplying.

Comment: I thought it's clear they're positive when $n>1$, but I could edit to be a bit more explicit about that

Comment: We usually expect students to be precise on manipulating  inequalities,as it is often confusional. Of course, it's clear for most people, but not necessarily for beginners, I think.